# Is there a way to wrap a scaled up text when it overflows div width via css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So my problem is I have this hover effect applied on a text which should change the font size of the text. At first I used font-size transition by enlarging the font size while being hovered. Transitioning the font-size works perfectly as it wraps the texts when it overflows the parent div. The only negative using font-size transition is, it has this annoying jitters as it grows. So I chose to use transform scale as this has a more appealing transition.In other words, I scale up the text when hovered. However, using this solution, I can't wrap the text when it overflows the parent div. Which made me to switch back to my former solution (Font size transition).
I am trying to figure how to best approach this issue

Comment: Try to add this CSS property `will-change: transform;` to the selector that performs the scale transformation. It will help the browser to anticipate the jitteriness problem.

Comment: Thank you looks like it did the trick

Comment: Glad it helped you. Am going to post it as an answer, so it can help others as well. Please accept it :).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this CSS property `will-change: transform;` to the selector that performs the scale transformation. It will help the browser to anticipate the jitteriness problem associated with the transform animation. [More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)